# Show custom field connected with post ID- Wordpress

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I have now this code/loop to get all the posts from one category:

```
// this needs to be modified
<?php
global $post;
$args = array('category' => 37, 'post_type' => 'post' ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?> 
// end this needs to be modified

<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "Title", true) ): ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Title", true); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I use it for showing the titles with permalinks in the sidebar.

When the user clicks on this post he can see the custom fields, which I can freely display on the post area. But the problem is, that I cannot duplicate them.

What I would like: 
I want to show some data on the post through INCLUDE call and shortcode (the problem is not in the implementation of that, this is working right 100%).

I want to modify the selected code above (with comments) to get the data only for the post ID and not for the whole category.

Hope I was clear, thanks!

Comment: I edited the code it was mistake when entering.. I think that it is really simple solution. I want to make INCLUDE call for some code and get the post->id from the post to show specific custom field for it. But since this custom field will be duplicated, I cannot make normal echo get_post_meta

Comment: What do you get when print_r($post)? I would think everything you need about the post should be in $post, no?

Comment: Let me preface it with this, how well do you know PHP? :)

Comment: can you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226242/match-the-post-id-on-the-include-ed-file-wordpress it is really simple solution probably, but I dont know how to paraphrase it

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand everything you're asking about. However, why not use WP_Query? WordPress's $id = get_the_id() within the loop will get the ID and $title = get_the_title($ID) will get the title... Am I missing something? In WordPress you usually give functionality it's own loop. So one for your sidebar plugin situation and another one for outputting to the page content area.

```
// this needs to be modified
    <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array('category' => 37, 'post_type' => 'post' ); 
    $postslist = get_posts( $args ); 
    foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
    ?> 
    // end this needs to be modified
    <?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> 
    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "Title", true) ): ?>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "Title", true); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```